# What makes this song sound so middle eastern?

Tags: theory, musicology, ethnomusicology

What makes [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7hlGqj3ImQI) to feel so middle eastern? I mean harmonically and theoretical context. Because as I see live [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fcaWN3ZJnhs) all performed instruments are western but still it feels so oriental.
Also [here are](https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/2428603) tabs for guitar If it will help to analyse

**EDIT1:** [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyWhFB9ijzA) is an interview, around 10.00 and she says they were watching Afghani music documentary. Will it be helpful to analyse the music?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What makes this song [sound] so Middle Eastern?

1. The rhythm is one often used in Middle Eastern music.
2. The instrumentation, consisting of percussion, and a chordophone such as an Oud,
   Sitar, guitar, etc.
3. The harmonic progression, using Bmin, Amaj, Gmaj or Emin, and F#min or F#maj, is
   common in 20th Century Middle Eastern music.
4. The articulation. In the first few minutes you can hear the soloist bending some of
   the notes a bit, not to reach the next scale note but only to accent the
   note.